# Passing params in java by reference

Tags: java

I'm a new comer form C#, and I know clearly that "Java is always pass-by-value."

But pass-by-reference is useful when we want to get multiple outputs from one method.

How can we get multiple outputs from one method in java, as in C#.

I know one way to do this -- use a generic wrapper class, and get value from the field.

```
class Wrapper<T> {
    public Wrapper(T value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value;
}
```

Is there another way to realize this effect?

Comment: Sadly, no. (15 chars)

Comment: In Java everything is pass by value.

Comment: This is the general idea behind all of them at least.

Comment: Why do you, and @LutzHorn think Java is pass-by-value only? Java passes primitives (int, long, double, char, etc.) by value, and **all** object instances are passed by reference. The `T value` parameter in your Wrapper example is passed by reference!

Comment: @rolfi, Do you really want to re-open [that can of worms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)?

Comment: @Rolfi - ::sigh:: **Because Java is only pass by value**. No. Really. The greatest sin ever committed by James Gosling was using the word 'reference' anywhere near Java.

Comment: Let's not argue definitions, all you need to know - you can happily modify an object passed to a function, it will modify the underlying object, but assigning a new value to it won't work (won't modify underlying object). Primitives work differently. It's the way C# works as well to my knowledge.

Comment: No, I don't want to open that can of worms again.... :0

Comment: The most rational way I've found of getting multiple returns from a method in java is to wrap them all up in a lightweight "struct like" class and return that. Usually all the returned objects are logically connected so a rational name for the stuct-like-class can usually be found

Comment: The OP clearly states that they know that Java is pass-by-value, so this question is *not* a duplicate of the canonical http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Java does not have *out* parameters. You can pass an object reference that the method is to modify to pretend that it has *out* parameters, but this isn't usually the best design and runs into other issues (multithreading and mutable state for one).

The best way to achieve a method that returns multiple values is to have the method return a type that contains multiple values.

Comment: Okey, I agree with you.
I'm using java other than C#. There are so many different and I need to adapt to these.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to *simulate* call by reference in Java is to pass a one-element array as a parameter.